# PHPCS warning for wordpress escaping function

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, phpcs

Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue shown in the picture ?

[image]

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow; please review [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask);  also please use text, not images, to present your question; what you are asking about is very suitable for the body of the question, and SO has markdown for formatting code and error messages in a clear and useful way

Answer (score 1):

The message shown for that line of code means exactly what it says.  If what it means by an "escaping function" is not clear, you can search the Web for lots of information about that.  It's a fundamental concept in programming, and in website programming in general.  You are going to need to understand it to write good, usable, robust webapps / websites.

Another place to start learning about what the message is telling you is noted right in the message: the WordPress Developer Handbook.

Answer (score 0):

When you are going to print any content as output and if you did not properly escaped it then phpcs will generate error and it will say Output should be run through an escaping function. Here i am describing some information how you can escape properly

`esc_html()` It will be used to escaped any content with html tag. This WILL NOT display HTML content, it is meant for being used inside HTML and will remove your HTML.

```
<span><?php echo esc_html($title); ?></span>
```

`esc_attr()` can be used when need to escape any html tag attributes

```
<div id="<?php echo esc_attr($variableId);"></div>
```

`wp_kses()` When you need to keep any content with html tag then you have to use wp_kses() where you can pass an array of allowed html tag and attributes so that those allowed html tag will not be truncated while printing.

```
  $title = '<span id="testid" class="className">This is a test content</span>'
  echo wp_kses($title, ['span' => [ 'id' => []]]);
```

So if your output need to contain any html tag seems like svg then you can use wp_kses() with allowed html tag so that the require tag would not wipe out with the escaping method and this will fix the phpcs output error issue.